# What is the purpose of `Kernel`?

Tags: ruby, oop

1. What is the purpose of the `Kernel` module? What would change if all the things currently defined on `Kernel` were defined on `Object`, and there were no such module as `Kernel`?
2. When I want to define a method that can be called on any object, should I define that on `Kernel` or on `Object`?

Comment: Sawa, much respect for you. I think this is a good question and I'm excited to see the answer.

Comment: @naomik Thank you. I see you appear on Ruby questions occasionally.

Comment: Here are a couple of interesting tidbits that may be related (for v.2.1.0): `Kernel.private_methods-Object.private_methods
=> [:append_features, :extend_object, :prepend_features, :refine, :module_function]` (why aren't these mixed into Object?) and `Kernel.singleton_methods.size => 61`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll start with a question: what would `self` be inside a typical [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html) method such as `puts`? The closest thing to a meaningful `self` inside `puts` would probably be the Ruby runtime itself. Similarly for other "methods that really want to be functions" like [`Array`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Array) or [`fork`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-fork). So you can look at `Kernel` as a dumping ground for methods that are, more or less, commands or messages to Ruby itself.

`Kernel` also has odd methods like [`sub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-sub) and [`chop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-chop) that are really only useful for one-off `ruby -e` scripts. These things tend to use `$_` as an implied `self` but I think they can be considered as special cases of the "commands to the Ruby runtime" as above.

Where does a method go when you want to be able to call that method on any object? I'd say that it would go into `Object`. If the method is really a function in disguise and has no meaningful `self`, then it would go into `Kernel`.

Comment: "Dumping ground"! Υou certainly have a way with words, μ.  Does `def Kernel.lets_see; puts "self = #{self}"; end; Kernel.lets_see => Kernel` shed any light?

Comment: There are also some things (like [Delegator](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_1/lib/delegate.rb#L43-L57)) which descend from BasicObject rather than Object, but then include Kernel. This wouldn’t be as simple if everything was tied up in Object.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall AFAIK BasicObject was recently (for some definitions of "recent") split out of Object for the reasons you state, Kernel has been around forever.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `module Kernel;def lets_see; puts self.inspect; end; end; lets_see` might be equally informative. Things in Kernel aren't talking to any particular object so `self` doesn't mean much in this context, that's why I want to call them "functions".

Comment: @muistooshort Correct, but the situation would still be difficult with BasicObject if everything in Kernel was defined explicitly in Object as you’d have no way to get at those “self-less” methods but to descend from Object anyway.

Comment: In the main environment, the implicit `self` is the special `<main>` object, which is an `Object`, and I think it would be natural if `self` within those function-style methods points to it.

Comment: @sawa Yeah but that's because `self` has to be something. I'm trying to say that `self` doesn't mean much inside a method like `puts`; I can say `'pancakes'.send(:puts, 11)` but that won't change the behavior of `puts` because `puts` is a function that is only a method in Kernel out of necessity. I admit that I find the terminology a little cumbersome here but I think you know what I'm getting at.

Comment: Further to mu's answer: any time you define a new method on `Kernel`, it should be `private` (so it will never be called with an explicit receiver).