# Why does the Ruby module Kernel exist?

Tags: ruby, oop

In the book *OO Design in Ruby*, Sandi Metz says that the main use of modules is to implement duck types with them and include them in every class needed. Why is the Ruby `Kernel` a module included in `Object`? As far as I know it isn't used anywhere else. What's the point of using a module?

Comment: I think you are right it probably would not be considered ideal OO design, and it's probably a mistake to go looking for reasons to justify it.

Comment: Is this is just [What is the purpose of Kernel?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22926586/479863) all over again?

Comment: You're right, it's pretty much anti-OO. `Kernel` contains all those "procedures" that exist for convencience and ignore their receiver (i.e. don't do anything with `self`).

Comment: How is it not ideal OO design?  (1) Sandi Metz is not the final authority on the use of modules.  (2) Anyway she said this is ***main use*** not the definitive use.  (3) If you were Matz, would you create a completely separate means of putting those methods in Object, when you already had module as a feature of Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally,

- *Methods in spirit* (that are applicable to any object), that is, methods that make use of the receiver, should be defined on the `Object` class, while
- *Procedures* (provided globally), that is, methods that ignore the receiver, should be collected in the `Kernel` module.

`Kernel#puts`, for example doesn't do anything with its receiver; it doesn't call private methods on it, it doesn't access any instance variables of it, it only acts on its arguments.

Procedures in Ruby are faked by using Ruby's feature that a receiver that is equal to `self` can be omitted. They are also often made private to prevent them from being called with an explicit receiver and thus being even more confusing. E.g., `"Hello".puts` would print a newline and nothing else since `puts` only cares about its arguments, not its receiver. By making it private, it can only be called as `puts "Hello"`.

In reality, due to the long history of Ruby, that separation hasn't always been strictly followed. It is also additionally complicated by the fact that some `Kernel` methods are documented in `Object` and vice versa, and even further by the fact that when you define something which *looks* like a global procedure, and which by the above reasoning should then end up in `Kernel`, it actually ends up as a private instance method in `Object`.

Answer (score 6):

As you already pointed out: Modules provide a way to collect and structure behavior, so does the Kernel module. This module is mixed in early into the class Object so every Ruby class will provide these methods. There is only a BasicObject before in hierarchy, it's child Objects purpose is only to get extended by the Kernel methods. BasicObject has only 7 methods that very very *basic* like `new`, `__send__` or `__id__`.

```
class Object < BasicObject
  include Kernel # all those many default methods we appreciate :)
end
```