# What is the private method Object#select?

Tags: ruby, internals

Like many others, I saw the exception

```
private method 'select' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

go by. What struck me as odd is that it didn't say `undefined method 'select' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. There was indeed such a method, and it was private!

What is this method?

I've found that it's defined on `Object`, and not just `NilClass`, but it's not defined on `BasicObject`. By using `#send`, I've found that it takes 1..4 arguments. The first three must be an array (or nil). And the last one must be convertible to a "time interval". In any case, when it doesn't throw an argument error, it hangs.

It's not in the ruby documentation because it's private. I don't really know how to read the C source code, and I haven't been able to find anything suggestive there. I expected to see something like the following line in `object.c`;

```
rb_define_private_method(rb_cObject, "select", select, 0);
```

But alas, I cannot.

What is this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [`Kernel#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-select). Per [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html) for the Kernel module:

> The Kernel module is included by class Object, so its methods are available in every Ruby object.

And in case you're curious what `select` does:

> #### select(read_array [, write_array [, error_array [, timeout]]]) → array or nil
>
> Calls select(2) system call. It monitors given arrays of `IO` objects, waits until one or more of `IO` objects are ready for reading, are ready for writing, and have pending exceptions respectively, and returns an array that contains arrays of those IO objects.

You can read more background on why Object includes Kernel in the answer to this question: [Why does the Ruby module Kernel exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289634/why-does-the-ruby-module-kernel-exist)

Answer (score 2):

You can check where method comes from using [Object#`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-method) and [Method#`owner`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html#method-i-owner):

```
nil.method(:select)
#=> #<Method: NilClass(Kernel)#select>
nil.method(:select).owner
#=> Kernel
```

So it is [Kernel#`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-select)